# NullPointerException at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent when using AWS 1.6

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-web-services

I have code that works fine with aws-java-sdk-1.0 . 
I have downloaded the source for aws.java.sdk-1.6.4, have built, and included the jar within my project.

I am getting a null pointer exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:86)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:34)
    at org.slideme.feed.model.business.catalog.store.DataStore.initAll(DataStore.java:215)
    at org.slideme.feed.web.Catalog.init(Catalog.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Anybody have any idea what changed between 1.0 and 1.6 such as API changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating the source code, it seems that it throws this exception because the property file `com/amazonaws/sdk/versionInfo.properties` doesn't have the property `platform`.

Comment: @meewoK https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/resources/com/amazonaws/sdk/versionInfo.properties

Comment: @meewoK Yeah, that's the problem. Java reads it like the property `version` has a value `1.6.4 platform = java`.

Comment: Very sloppy...unless there was a mixup with line endings (*ux vs win). Such an error in code released from a large company? 
It feels like when they said santa clause doesn't exist.